# Increase Count On Server Every Time iOS User Clicks Area

Tags: ios, wordpress

Yea, worst title ever, I know.  I have some blog apps that use Wordpress.  I parse the XML feed from wordpress, and create a `TableView` from this data, each row an article.  At first, I had it push a new view controller that contained a `UIWebView` that would load the `<link>` tag of that XML entry.

I began getting rejected by Apple, as the app was not different enough from a Safari experience, due to it loading the same URL as the article would load in Safari.

To combat this, I took the entire article from the XML, and embed it within a custom HTML String I had written, and store that as a property, and have the web view load that HTML.

This works fine, and I can customize very easily the way the article reads, and it doesn't look just like Safari, so Apple approves the apps.  The issue is that those that read the article in the app never get counted towards the stats of views on wordpress.  Is there any way you can think of that I can increase the stats without actually going to the link for wordpress?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad It has plenty of advantages over Safari, there were other features I didn't discuss that the app DOES, but were not relevant to my question.  Getting an app reviewer at times to explore the entire app instead of JUST one aspect of it can be a pain, so I jumped through his hoop on that one area, in order to make the web view of an article in my app different from viewing it in Safari.  However, You have not even attempted to answer my question.  How could I go about increasing stats in wordpress, without actually ever visiting that link?

Comment: Obviously wordpress does not count the XML accesses. So you have to do that on server side. Maybe you can configure that. Maybe there is an API for that. What did you try so far, in particular what docs did you read to solve that problem?

Comment: There are no docs for wordpress.com server side api access.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Bottom line question is, can you increase Wordpress stats for an article without ever going to the URL of said article.  It doesn't matter what value you place on an app, or what work I have done.  I have done NO work on this issue, because I do not even know if it is a possibility to do what I am asking, which is why the question was "Is there any way you can think of that I can increase the stats without actually going to the link for wordpress?"